# How to use the same button class for one same and one different action?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am using 16 images as services displayers, which I intent to use as buttons when cliked to toggle a div (first action) and write something in it (second action) using jquery.

For the moment its working perfectly for one image and it's button class="flip", toggling my div id="panel" and writing in the p id="paneldesc" element. I have also tried 16 buttons using ids instead of class, all fine.

Now I would like to know if it is possible to use the same button with class flip on all photos, having the same first action (slidetoggle) but writing something different each as the second action. And besides, I would like to know if it is possible to reverse the sliding effect so that 8 of my buttons which are below the div as oposed to the others, slide up for showing the div and back down.

My code :

```
<div class="service">
<div class="container">
  <img src="./Images/SSIS.jpg" alt="Individual Sessions" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
  <div class="text"><button class="flip"><i class="fa-solid fa-image-portrait"></i><br 
   />Individual sessions</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="panel">
<p id="paneldesc"></p>
</div>

<script>
$(".flip").click(function() {
  $("#panel").slideToggle({
  });
  $("#paneldesc").text("COCO");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, give them an extra attribute like `add-txt=""`.

Then get that attribute of the clicked element `$(this).attr('add-txt');`.

The `this` refers to the clicked flip class `$(".flip").click`, and store it in a var.

Last, enter the var `.text(addtxt)` to add the text you want from that clicked button.

```
    <div class="service">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="./Images/SSIS.jpg" alt="Individual Sessions" class="image">
      <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text"><button class="flip" add-txt="insert this text"><i class="fa-solid fa-image-portrait"></i><br 
       />Individual sessions</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="panel">
    <p id="paneldesc"></p>
    </div>
    
    <script>
    $(".flip").click(function() {
      var addtxt = $(this).attr('add-txt');
      $("#panel").slideToggle({
  });
      $("#paneldesc").text(addtxt);
    });
```

Your second question isn't really clear to me. But maybe to point you in the right direction because it's about the sliding. You can also use `slideUp()` & `slideDown()` in jQuery when it doesn't need to toggle.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late, I will test and get back. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's brilliant, will keep the toggle to close when needed, thank you again !

Comment: Yw ;) don't forget to click the accept the answer. ✌️

Comment: I don't have the prievilegies for that yet, where should that be?

Comment: Just did, have a great day.